# Run-time error 3021

Tags: ms-access, vba

Not entirely sure how to fix this code that is giving me a run-time error 3021: No Current Record.

The purpose is to click this button and it will populate a few text boxes with the results of the first record of the query. It is then supposed to populate another two text boxes with the next record of results from the query using the MoveNext.

```
Private Sub btnSCC07_Click()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rsTable As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsQuery As DAO.Recordset


Set dbs = CurrentDb

Set rsQuery = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM qrySccS2 WHERE PAYORNAME = 'Medicaid' AND OVERRIDECODESALL = 7", dbOpenDynaset)

rsQuery.FindFirst ("[PAYORNAME]='Medicaid'")
num1 = rsQuery!PAYPLANNAME
num2 = rsQuery!Count
txtMedicaid9 = num1
txtMedicaidCount9 = num2
Debug.Print (txtMedicaid9)


rsQuery.MoveNext
Debug.Print ("Test")
num3 = rsQuery!PAYPLANNAME
num4 = rsQuery!Count
txtMedicaid10 = num3
txtMedicaidCount10 = num4


rsQuery.Close
Set rsQuery = Nothing
```

So the first section works, but it's when it reaches the line num3 = rsQuery!PAYPLANNAME is where it throws the error. Thank you in advance for any insight you may be able to provide.

Comment: you need to check the record count to make sure you have results returned.  rsQuery.RecordCount or rsQuery.EOF

Comment: @Sorceri hmm so I just tried that and the debug.print returned 1...... but when I run the query itself with the parameters it returns 12 results?

Comment: Use lines just after opening the recordset `rsQuery.MoveLast rsQuery.MoveFirst` to force the count. Why do you have a MoveNext without a loop?

Comment: @June7 So I inserted `rsQuery.MoveLast` and  `rsQuery.MoveFirst` right after the `Set rsQuery = dbs.OpenRecordset` line and it is still return 1 in the immediate window and throwing the error.

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-29.html#RecordCount_without_MoveLast

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, the `.RecordCount` will just return a 1 or a 0 depending on if there are records. So seeing how it is returning a 1, that signifies that there are still records that can be accessed. I'm still unsure why I would still get run-time error 3021 even with the `rsQuery.MoveLast` and `Debug.Print(rsQuery.RecordCount)` if there are records that can be accessed? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: Reread the question and now understand why don't Loop. <Head slap here> - perhaps the FindFirst finds value on last record and then the MoveNext is to EOF. Test if EOF before try to saving to num3 and num4. Why denormalize data? Count is a reserved word and should not use reserved words as names for anything.

Comment: Lol no worries.  So I Changed the `.FindFirst` to `.MoveFirst` and then inserted a `Debug.Print (rsQuery.EOF)` in three places and it seems as though you are correct.  I put the `Debug.Print (rsQuery.EOF)` after `rsQuery.MoveNext` and it is returning True so I believe that means that there are no records after it does the `.MoveNext`..... Wonder why that is?

Comment: Cannot replicate issue. After MoveLast I get proper record count of 8 instead of 1. Since you only retrieve records with 'Medicaid' why even do FindFirst? This SQL in Access will return 12 records?

Comment: Hm that's bizarre. Yeah it's supposed to return 12 records. I actually replaced FindFirst with MoveFirst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should play safe using *NoMatch* and *EOF*:

```
Set rsQuery = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM qrySccS2 WHERE PAYORNAME = 'Medicaid' AND OVERRIDECODESALL = 7", dbOpenDynaset)

If rsQuery.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rsQuery.FindFirst "[PAYORNAME]='Medicaid'"
    If Not rsQuery.NoMatch Then
        num1 = rsQuery!PAYPLANNAME.Value
        num2 = rsQuery!Count.Value
        txtMedicaid9 = num1
        txtMedicaidCount9 = num2
        Debug.Print txtMedicaid9

        If Not rsQuery.EOF Then
            rsQuery.MoveNext
            Debug.Print "Test"
            num3 = rsQuery!PAYPLANNAME.Value
            num4 = rsQuery!Count.Value
            txtMedicaid10 = num3
            txtMedicaidCount10 = num4
        End If
    End If
End If
rsQuery.Close

Set rsQuery = Nothing
```

Comment: So for some reason when I remove the criteria in the actual query that it is running from but keep it in the code, it gives me the No Current Record found error. Any ideas regarding that?

Comment: Oh I figured it out... apparently I had limited the query to returning only 10 results.... durrr